# Inequalities for trace of a product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

For positive-definite matrices $A$ and $B$ the following inequalities hold:
$$
 0\leq\lambda_{\min}(A)\lambda_{\max}(B)\leq\lambda_{\min}(A){\rm Tr}(B)\leq{\rm Tr} (AB)\leq\lambda_{\max}(A){\rm Tr} B\leq{\rm Tr}(A){\rm Tr}(B).
$$
Сan they (or some of them) be valid for the case of semi-definite (or indefinite) matrices?

Comment: They are all valid for positive-semidefinite matrices. The only issue is that some of them can be trivial, e.g. when $\lambda_{\min}(A) = 0$.

Comment: Isn't the inequality $${\rm Tr} (AB)\geq\lambda_{\min}(A){\rm Tr}(B)$$ valid for $A\succeq0$ and any $B$?

Comment: No, you should be able to find counterexamples quite quickly with $2\times 2$ diagonal matrices. Moreover if the matrices have complex entries the inequality may not even make sense.